# Set user field in a form object created using ModelForm

Tags: python, django, forms, post

I have a registration form that when the user enters in valid registration data in it, it logs the user in and redirects the user to another form to enter more data. This new form contains more data about the user and is created using the ModelForm class below:

```
class UserProfileAddForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ('user')
```

and the UserProfile model looks like:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    GRADE_YEAR_CHOICES = (
        ('FR', 'Freshman'),
        ('SO', 'Sophomore'),
        ('JR', 'Junior'),
        ('SR', 'Senior'),
        ('GR', 'Graduate')
    )

    school = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    grade_year = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=GRADE_YEAR_CHOICES)
    gpa = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
```

Where the user field is a ForeignKey to Django's User object. I am having a hard time setting the user field to the user making the request. Here is what I have tried in my views.py

**First attempt:**

```
def more(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileAddForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            form.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/register/success/')
    else:
        form = UserProfileAddForm()
        variables = RequestContext(request, {
            'form': form
```

**Second attempt:**

```
def more(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileAddForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            form.user = User.objects.filter(username=request.user)
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/register/success/')
    else:
        form = UserProfileAddForm()
        variables = RequestContext(request, {
            'form': form
        })
        return render_to_response('registration/more.html', variables)
```

Either way I try it does not seem to save the data to the database. It will however redirect me to the success page as though it did save successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`form.save()` returns an instance of the model being saved. It's there that you need to set the user, then save that instance.

```
profile = form.save(commit=False)
profile.user = request.user
profile.save()
```

Note that getting the user from the database based on the value of `request.user` is pointless, as `request.user` already is the correct User object.

Comment: That worked perfectly. So just so I understand the difference, in  `form` object you can not actually change the values of the instance, but in `profile`  object you can ? Why could I not just do `form.user = request.user` directly?

Comment: @NicYoung, Django [form objects contain a collection of Field objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#form-objects), which as you can [read here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/) are not anything like the object you're trying to modify. `form.save()` creates a new "instance" of the object you are saving, and that's the one you can modify.

Comment: @Dirk Thank you for the clarification. So actually instantiating the object makes it modifiable. That is something I will have to get used to.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that you make this change in second attempt:

```
        with_profile = form.save(commit=False)
        with_profile.user = request.user
        form.save()
        ...
```

Problem is that you are adding `user` property to `form` object insteat to `form.instance` object.

**Edited**

When I posted first answer I mistaked in user assignement. @Dirk has commented it below and now is fixed. Thanks @Dirk. Problem was that a query set is assigned to `with_profile.user` insteat a single model.

Comment: A modification of the first attempt would be better as it eliminates a run to the database for a piece of data you already have in `request.user`. Also, won't the second attempt return a QuerySet and not a User object?

Comment: I guess I am having a hard time understanding the difference between the `form` object and `instance` object. I have made the change you suggest and now I am getting an Integerity Error: `gradebook_userprofile.user_id may not be NULL`, so it doesn't seem to be setting the user field on the instance object.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you need to understand is you get the model instance when you do
i.e. in you case

```
profile = form.save(commit =False)
```

And when you save the model object it does not saves any Many To Many relationship. Which you need to do after you save the model object. By doing this,

```
form.save_m2m()
```

So, just add the last piece of code after you have saved the model object.