# invalid literal for int() with base 10: when trying to save an object

Tags: python, django

I know there are plenty of posts here with the same title and error. I went through as many as I could, but the codes posted are not really similar to mine. Hence I am forced to ask.

I am trying to save a "Games" object to the database. The relevant source files are posted below:

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Usertypes(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    usertype = models.TextField()                   

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user_name

class Games(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    url = models.URLField()
    developer = models.OneToOneField(User)
    price = models.FloatField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py:

```
def addgame(request):

    c={}
c.update(csrf(request))
saved = False
if request.method == 'POST':
    name = request.POST['name']
    #print(name)
    category = request.POST['category']
    #print(category)
    url = request.POST['url']
    #print(url)
    developer = request.POST['developer']
    #print(developer)
    price = request.POST['price']
    #print(price)
    game = Games(name,category,url,developer,price)
    game.save()
    saved = True
    return render_to_response('gamestore/developer_homepage.html',{'saved':saved},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
import gamestore.views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'wsdProject.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$','gamestore.views.home'),
    url(r'^login/','gamestore.views.login_view'),
    url(r'^logout/','gamestore.views.logout_view'),
    url(r'^registration/','gamestore.views.registration'),
    url(r'^addgame/','gamestore.views.addgame'),
    url(r'^gamestore/', include('gamestore.urls', namespace="gamestore")),
```

Finally, my error:

ValueError at /addgame/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'NFS'

The error traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/addgame/

Django Version: 1.7.1
Python Version: 3.2.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'gamestore')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/mukhera3/djangoenv/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response 111.response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/mukhera3/Desktop/game_store/wsdProject/gamestore/views.py" in addgame 137.game.save()
File "/home/mukhera3/djangoenv/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save 591.force_update=force_update,update_fields=update_fields)
File "/home/mukhera3/djangoenv/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base 619.updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
File "/home/mukhera3/djangoenv/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table 681.forced_update)
File "/home/mukhera3/djangoenv/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_update 711.filtered = base_qs.filter(pk=pk_val)
File "/home/mukhera3/djangoenv/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in filter 691.return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/mukhera3/djangoenv/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/db models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude 709.clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
File "/home/mukhera3/djangoenv/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q 1287. clause, require_inner = self._add_q(where_part, self.used_aliases)
File "/home/mukhera3/djangoenv/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _add_q 1314. current_negated=current_negated, connector=connector)
File "/home/mukhera3/djangoenv/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_filter 1186.condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
File "/home/mukhera3/djangoenv/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_lookup 1094. return final_lookup(lhs, rhs)
File "/home/mukhera3/djangoenv/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py" in __init__82.self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
File "/home/mukhera3/djangoenv/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py" in get_prep_lookup 85.return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_lookup(self.lookup_name, self.rhs)
File "/home/mukhera3/djangoenv/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_lookup 646.return self.get_prep_value(value)
File "/home/mukhera3/djangoenv/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_value 915.return int(value)

Exception Type: ValueError at /addgame/
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'NFS'
```

Can anyone suggest how I should change the way the Games object is getting saved? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: my guess is its around `developer = request.POST['developer']`. It looks like you're going to get some sort of string from the web front end, and it wants an id.

Comment: The value for `developer` in the POST data would be the primary key. The `Game` model expects `developer` to be an instance of the Developer model, not an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should be using a ModelForm for this, which will make everything much easier.

That said, you can fix your code by getting the actual User object for the developer:

```
developer = User.objects.get(username=request.POST['developer'])
```

but if you used a ModelForm, you wouldn't need to do this. Plus you'll have the advantage that your users' entries will actually be validated, rather than crashing when data is missing which is what will happen now.

Comment: Also, @user3033194 your view code is really antiquted. I'm not sure if you're following some sort of tutorial, but if you are, it out-of-date by about 6 years.

Comment: actually, I have a doubt here as well - if I use a ModelForm, will the "developer" field be displayed as well as an enterable field in the form?

Comment: If you want. By default it would be a drop-down of all users, but you could configure that to be editable if you prefer, although you would then need to add in some similar logic to find the actual User.

Comment: Also note the `Games(name,category,url,developer,price)`.  You should use named arguments: `Game(name=name, category=category, ...)`

Comment: @Daniel Roseman - I am sure you are right, and I have used  ModelForms elsewhere, but the problem is - the developer should not have to enter the ID himself. It should be displayed on the template as a non-enterable field with the ID of the logged-in developer, who is actually adding the game.

Comment: Well that is a competely different question, which is well covered in many many other answers on this site, see for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056455/set-user-field-in-a-form-object-created-using-modelform).

Comment: Thank you all for your help and advice, I think I'll change to modelforms!!

Comment: It's a nitpick, but I feel that using the singular form of model names makes readability down the line a lot easier, e.g. `UserType` and `Game` versus `Usertypes` and `Games`... `games = Games.objects.all` just feels weird to me.